# value being declared and only used outside if statement in typescript

Tags: typescript, scope, constants, declaration

In typescript I have code as follows:

```
let a = 'null'
if (condition) {
  const a = 'condition was met'
}
const result = getName(a)
```

However, compilation/build is failing because there is a yellow line underneath the a in `const a = 'condition was met'` saying `a is declared but its value is never read`. Would anyone know of a fix to this, so that a can be used later and I can change its value in the if statement? If I try removing `let a = 'null'` I then get a red underline under a in `const result = getName(a)` saying `Cannot find name 'a'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), `let a` and `const a` inside of if block is not same.

you should write like this:

```js
let a = 'null'
if (condition) {
  a = 'condition was met'
}
const result = getName(a)
```

also I think you should read docs about [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)